# Doctrine-module could not find driver PDO

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine

I have had a really annying problem for the last couple of days... A similar question have been asked many times, but none of their solutions have worked for me.

Mainly doctrine-module cant find my PDO driver:

```
vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping 
--namespace="Album\\Entity\\" --force --from-database annotation ./module/Album/src/

[PDOException]
could not find driver
```

I have PDO installed and it works in my other projects... PHP CLI have proven to be a problem for other users, but it seems to be available to me:

```
$ php -m | grep -G PDO -i
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
```

I can even do this:

```
$ php -r "die(new PDO("localhost"));"

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name' in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 Command line code(1): PDO->__construct('localhost')
#1 {main}
```

Which suggests to me that PHP-CLI does indeed have PDO support (and ofcourse mysql support)...

Can anyone help me?

Edited: 
Here are my configuration: Obviously masked the password :)

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'user' => 'zend_tutorial',
                'password' => '**********',
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'dbname' => 'zend_tutorial',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I would suggest this is probably a doctrine configuration thing. Can you paste your doctrine config in here?

Comment: Hi! I just updated the question to include my configuration... All of this is in my local.php autoloaded config...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the DrvierClass configuration as  **Jenko** said,

This:

```
'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver'
```

Should be this instead:

```
'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver'
```

Notice the MySQL!

Thanks Jenko:)